# Saving NSDate to File With writeToURL

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsdate, nsdata

I'm building an image cache in the app I'm working on, where the cache is an NSMutableDictionary.

Initially the dictionary looked like this:

```
NSMutableDictionary *imageCacheDictionary = [NSMutableDictionary initWithContentsOfURL:imageCacheURL];
//alloc-init imageCacheDictionary if nil
NSData *imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image, 1.0);
NSString *imageURLAsString = [imageURL absoluteString];
[imageCacheDictionary setObject:imageData forKey:imageURLAsString];
if ([imageCacheDictionary writeToURL:cacheURL atomically:YES]) {
    NSLog(@"file written");
} else {
    NSLog(@"file NOT written");
}
```

Which worked swimmingly.

Then when I decided to add code to maintain the cache at under a certain size, I tried to add a tag so that I could delete the oldest photos first.

```
NSMutableDictionary *imageCacheDictionary = [NSMutableDictionary initWithContentsOfURL:imageCacheURL];
//alloc-init imageCacheDictionary if nil
NSData *imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image, 1.0);
NSString *imageURLAsString = [imageURL absoluteString];
NSDate *currentTime = [NSDate date];
NSDictionary *imageDataWithTime = @{currentTime : imageDataWithTime};
[imageCacheDictionary setObject:imageDataWithTime forKey:imageURLAsString];
if ([imageCacheDictionary writeToURL:cacheURL atomically:YES]) {
    NSLog(@"file written");
} else {
    NSLog(@"file NOT written");
}
```

Which did not work.

To my knowledge, NSDate is property-list compliant so writeToURL should let you write to disk, but nope.

Then I tried converting it to NSData with NSKeyedArchiver.

```
...
NSData *currentTimeAsData = [NSKeyedArchiver archivedDataWithRootObject:[NSDate date]];
NSDictionary *imageDataWithTime = @{currentTimeAsData : imageData};
...
```

Still not working.

But if I convert the NSDate object to NSString or just replace it with an NSString, it works fine.

```
...
NSString *currentTime = [[NSDate date] description];
NSDictionary *imageDataWithTime = @{currentTime : imageData};
...
```

Or:

```
...
NSString *currentTime = @"Hey! Now is now!";
NSDictionary *imageDateWithTime = @{currentTime : imageData};
...
```

So.... why? If both NSDate and NSData are property list compliant, why are neither of them writing to disk inside the nested dictionary, while NSString is writing fine?

Comment: can you please paste imageURl also?

Comment: This link might help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5361630/iphone-writing-nsmutabledictionary-to-file

Comment: imageURL is a property set by the VC which creates the segue to this VC, so in my actual code it's self.imageURL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Property list keys must be strings, they cannot be dates. [This page here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/cocoa/conceptual/PropertyLists/AboutPropertyLists/AboutPropertyLists.html) says:

> And although NSDictionary and CFDictionary objects allow their keys to be objects of any type, **if the keys are not string objects, the collections are not property-list objects.**

What you need is a dictionary inside a dictionary, for example:

```
NSDictionary *imageInfo = @{ @"date" : [NSDate date], @"data" : imageData };

NSDictionary *mainCacheDict = @{ imageURLAsString : imageInfo };
```

This way, the cache dictionary still has string URLs as keys, but the values are a second dictionary which contains both the date and the image data (accessed by using the string keys `@"date"` and `@"data"`). This is property-list compliant, so you can continue to use the `writeToFile:` and `initWithContentsOfFile:` methods.

Comment: YES! Thank you. That completely did the trick. I totally missed that sentence while looking over the Property List documentation.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was in your data which you are making in dictionary. Try below:-

```
NSData *imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image, 1.0);
NSString *imageURLAsString = [imageURL absoluteString];
NSDate *currentTime = [NSDate date];
//Below your code has modified
  [imageCacheDictionary setObject:currentTime forKey:imageDataWithTime];
  NSDictionary *imageDataWithTime =[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:imageCacheDictionary forKey:imageURLAsString];

if ([imageDataWithTime writeToFile:@"yourPath" atomically:YES]) {
    NSLog(@"file written");
} else {
    NSLog(@"file NOT written");
}
```

Comment: I don't think I made it clear in my code so I apologize for that: imageCacheDictionary is an NSMutableDictionary retrieved from disk which, if not nil, already contains image : URL pairings, so I need to just add the new image I'm caching and then resave the same dictionary back.

I've modified my code in the original comment.

Answer (score 0):

Try this: I have modified your code:

```
NSData *imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image, 1.0);
    NSDate *currentTime = [NSDate date];
    NSDictionary *imageDataWithTime = @{currentTime : imageDataWithTime};
    NSMutableData *data = [[NSMutableData alloc] init];
    NSKeyedArchiver *archiver = [[NSKeyedArchiver alloc] initForWritingWithMutableData:data];
    [archiver encodeObject:imageDataWithTime forKey:@"Some Key Value"];
    [archiver finishEncoding];
    if ([data writeToURL:cacheURL atomically:YES]) {
        NSLog(@"file written");
    } else {
        NSLog(@"file NOT written");
    }
```