# Writing NSDictionary with custom objects to file

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsdictionary, nsobject

I have a `NSDictionary` with an array of custom objects, called `MAClass`es. I try writing the dict to file, simple method:

```
- (void)writeDictToFileWithContent:(NSDictionary *)contentDict {
    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
    NSString *filePath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"/userdata.txt"];


    [contentDict writeToFile:filePath atomically:YES];

}
```

and then I read using

```
- (NSDictionary *)readFromDict {
    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
    NSString *filePath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"/userdata.txt"];

    NSDictionary *contentDict = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithContentsOfFile:filePath];

    return contentDict;
}
```

The array of objects I'm trying to write is a custom NSObject, which is structured kinda like this:

```
@interface MAAssignment : NSObject

@property (nonatomic, strong) NSDate *date;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *assignmentName;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSNumber *totalPoints;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSNumber *recievedPoints;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSNumber *classAverage;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSNumber *extraCredit;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSNumber *notGraded;
```

Which represents a class.

I was earlier using just arrays of nsstrings and nsnumbers, and it could read and write fine. When I switched the the MAClass object it returned an empty dict when I tried to read.

This is probably why: [iPhone - Writing NSMutableDictionary to file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5361630/iphone-writing-nsmutabledictionary-to-file)

What should I do to write the dict instead?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to serialize your custom objects, one way to do it is the following, in your custom class write the following two methods encoding/decoding each property that you want to persist, then I am not sure if writeToFile will actually use this, but I do know that you can create NSData from your object and write it to file with the following method

```
     //archive dictionary and serializable objects to NSData  
     NSData *serializedData= [NSKeyedArchiver archivedDataWithRootObject:myDict];

//Unarchive 
    NSData *myData=[NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:appFile];

    NSMutableDictionary* myDict= (NSMutableDictionary*)[NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithData:myData];
```

Here are the two methods you need in your custom objects:

```
- (void)encodeWithCoder:(NSCoder *)coder
{
    [coder encodeInt:self.propOne forKey:@"PropOne"];
    [coder encodeObject:self.propTwo forKey:@"PropTwo"];
    ...

}
// Decode an object from an archive
- (id)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)coder
{
    self = [super init];
    self.propOne=[coder decodeIntegerForKey:@"PropOne"];
    self.propTwo=[coder decodeObjectForKey:@"PropTwo"];
     ..

    return self;
}
```

Hope that helps

Comment: What would you recommend making the objects and ints? I don't totally understand the whole `PropOne`, `PropTwo` thing.

Comment: @user3451350 The PropOne/PropTwo are the properties of your class, i just named them that for examples sake...

Comment: `- (void)encodeWithCoder:(NSCoder *)encoder {
    [encoder encodeObject:self forKey:@"self"];
}` |
`- (id)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)decoder {
    if (self = [super init]) {
        self = [decoder decodeObjectForKey:@"self"];
    }
    return self;
}`
 
Do these methods work??

Comment: @user3451350 no, you cant decode self...you have properties as part of your object, you have listed them in your question, now just write one of these lines [coder encodeObject:self.propTwo forKey:@"PropTwo"]; for each property (all your properties are objects)

Comment: BTW your properties are date, assignmentName, totalPoints etc etc

Comment: Set up those two methods http://i.imgur.com/cCufiv4.png, im getting this errror: `-[MAClass encodeWithCoder:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0xba366b0`

Comment: are these inside your MAClass? Seems like thsoe properties are part of MAAssignment, you need to implement those methods in MAClass as well

Comment: Right, I'm an idiot. Do I also need to encode all the properties of MAAssignment? Which itself is a property of MAClass?

Comment: Yes you do, and then just encode object on that property..

Answer (score -2):

you can not save nsdictionary with custom objects . try saving nsdictionary in encoded form to file and retrieve the dictionary then decode it. then i think you will get your object.
try this one

```
- (void)writeDictToFileWithContent:(NSDictionary *)contentDict {
    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
    NSString *filePath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"/userdata.txt"];

 NSData *data = [NSKeyedArchiver archivedDataWithRootObject:contentDict]; 
    [data writeToFile:filePath atomically:YES];


}

- (NSDictionary *)readFromDict {
    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
    NSString *filePath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"/userdata.txt"];

    NSDictionary *contentDict = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithContentsOfFile:filePath];


    return [NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithData:contentDict];;
}
```

Comment: `-[MAClass encodeWithCoder:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0xba92af0`
Do I need to add an encode with coder method the my `MAClass` NSObject?

Comment: yes , you had to implement those methods also

Comment: you have to use read for archived data from file is  NSData *storedData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:[self myDataFilePath]];
       return [NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithData:storedData];